# simplify huge if statements - design pattern?

Tags: php

i potentially have a set of if statements that look like this:

```
if (a and b and c and d) {
  // do stuff
} else (!a and b and c and d) {
  // do something else
} else (!a and !b and c and D) {
  // do yet something else
} ...
```

and so on for all possible permutations.

i thought of doing this:

```
switch ((a ? 'Y' : 'N') . (b ? 'Y' : 'N') . (c ? 'Y' : 'N') . (d ? 'Y' : 'N')) {

  case 'YNYN':
    // do stuff
    break;

  case 'NNNN':
    // etc.
    break;

}
```

is there a better way?

Comment: Use less if-statements. Seriously, this question is so vague

Comment: Well don't use the switch, please.

Comment: I don't think `and` would work here (inside the switch). Use `.`? http://codepad.org/X4fIQsSz

Comment: @longneck shouldn't the second and third else be elseif

Comment: How exactly do these cases look like? Is it just these three cases?

Comment: can you explain the context where this is used please.

Comment: @Gumbo: he says right in the 2nd non-code line: *and so on for all possible permutations*.  So it should therefore be all 16 possible cases...

Comment: @dogbert is correct. Those ands should have been periods.

Comment: I'm not really digging and of these answers. I can't see strategy pattern being any better. Instead of keeping the two logics close together, I now have them separated across multiple classes. And the performance overhead of all those function calls is too much considering how frequently I have to hit this code path.

Answer (score 9):

What I would likely do (without knowing the specifics) is build a series of classes for each state.  Then push the *doStuff* onto that class:

```
class DoStuff { //The Client
    protected $strategies = array();
    public function addStrategy(iDoStuffStrategy $strategy) {
        $this->strategies[] = $strategy;
    }
    public function doStuff ($a, $b, $c, $d) {
        foreach ($this->strategies as $strategy) {
            if ($strategy->test($a, $b, $c, $d)) {
                return $strategy->doStuff();
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException('Unhandleable Situation!');
    }
}

interface iDoStuffStrategy {
    // Return a bool if you can handle this situation
    public function test($a, $b, $c, $d);
    // Execute the implementation
    public function doStuff();
}
```

Then, each class would look like this:

```
public function StrategyFoo implements iDoStuffStrategy {
    public function test($a, $b, $c, $d) {
        return $a && $b && $c && $d;
    }
    public function doStuff() {
        //DoStuff!
    }
}
public function StrategyBar implements iDoStuffStrategy {
    public function test($a, $b, $c, $d) {
        return !$a && $b && $c && $d;
    }
    public function doStuff() {
        //DoStuff!
    }
}
```

It's basically an implementation of the [Strategy Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy).  Doing it that way allows you to separate out the decision tree.

Comment: +1 This approach or something similar is what's called for.  Anytime you have a long set of switch statements it's probably best to use more OOP style thinking.

Comment: @ircmaxwell...I'm trying to use a version of this code and am curious if I'm missing something. How does the `addStrategy` method add the objects to the `$strategy` variable? I really love this design pattern and would like to implement it, but I cannot get that part to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should considering solving this problem with decision trees, where different nodes are possible end states.
then you can compose your problem in a tree, and get rid of all these ifs ....

Answer (score 0):

I took a similar approach to your case statement once when I was needing to aggregate data based on a set of conditions, of which there were five switches that could be on or off.

For dealing with aggregating information about the possible situations this worked fine, but outside of that  use case, if there are truly n^2 different actions, then I'd stick with the multiple if statements.  If there are not really that many permutations, I'd group the like results together to lessen the number of ifs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way.

Oh, did you want more detail than that? Well, you appear to have some sort of truth table with four variables. Are there 16 possible outcomes (2^4), or are you only interested in a subset? If there is one variable that has a roughly equal number of outcomes either way, perhaps use that as your topmost if statements, and use nested ifs.

```
if (b) {
  // cases where b is true
  if (...)
    ...
} else {
  // cases where b is false
  if (...)
    ...
}
```

You could also use a switch statement, but rather than a string made of Y and N use bitfields.

Answer (score 0):

I would treat your four booleans as four bits, so as an integer between 0 and 15. I'd create an array with 16 elements, and store a function pointer in each element of the array. Every time you need to do this, I'd evaluate the booleans into a bit pattern, convert to int, and call the method stored in that index of the array.

I know you're asking about PHP, which I'm afraid I don't know. In C#, you could do something like this:

```
static class Multiplexer
{
    public static string Multiplex(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d)
    {
        var i = 0;
        i |= (a ? 1 : 0) << 3;
        i |= (b ? 1 : 0) << 2;
        i |= (c ? 1 : 0) << 1;
        i |= (d ? 1 : 0);
        return _functions[i]();
    }

    private static Func<string>[] _functions = new Func<string>[] {
        () => { return "pie";},
        () => { return "index 1"; },
        () => { return DateTime.Now.ToString(); },
        () => { return "pie";},
        () => { return "index 1"; },
        () => { return DateTime.Now.ToString(); },
        () => { return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName; },
        () => { return ""; },
        () => { return "pie";},
        () => { return "index 1"; },
        () => { return DateTime.Now.ToString(); },
        () => { return "pie";},
        () => { return "index 1"; },
        () => { return DateTime.Now.ToString(); },
        () => { return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName; },
        () => { return ""; }};
}
```